# How to echo values from the same field of the related table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, alias

I have two related tables: Contracts with 3 columns: ContractsID, AreaManager and AreaLeader. Then I have Employees table with 2 columns: EmployeesID, EmployeeName. The EmployeeID is both foreign key for AreaManager and AreaLeader.  I am trying to create a SELECT query to echo  ContractID, Area Manager's name and Area Leader's name.

This is what I have;

```
$query = "SELECT Contracts.ContractsID, Contracts.AreaLeader, Contracts.AreaManager, Employees.EmployeeName FROM Contracts 
INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = Contracts.AreaManager
INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeeID = Contracts.AreaLeader
```

However, the query doesn't work. I believe that I should use table aliases but I kind of struggling with this.

I tried this but it  didn't work:

```
$query = "SELECT c.ContractsID, m.Employees.EmployeeName as ManagerName, l.Employees.EmployeeName as LeaderName

FROM c.Contracts 

JOIN Employees m ON m.EmployeeID = c.AreaManager

JOIN Employees l ON l.EmployeeID = c.AreaLeader
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Your second query looks fine to me, except `m.Employees.EmployeeName` and `l.Employees.EmployeeName` which should be `m.EmployeeName` and `l.EmployeeName` respectively.

Comment: Did you run your query directly on mysql? Did it return results? How did you decide that query doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your original query does not work is because you join with `Employees` twice, and you need to alias them to make a distinction.

```
$query = "SELECT Contracts.ContractsID, Contracts.AreaLeader, Contracts.AreaManager, Employees.EmployeeName FROM Contracts 
INNER JOIN Employees Employee1 ON Employee1.EmployeeID = Contracts.AreaManager
INNER JOIN Employees Employee2 ON Employee2.EmployeeID = Contracts.AreaLeader
```

You do not need to alias `Contracts` unless you want to do so.

Your second query fails because you did not alias `Contracts` properly.  You should have put `Contracts c` instead of `c.Contracts`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct approach on your second query, but you have syntax error in it. your query would look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT c.ContractsID, m.EmployeeName as ManagerName, l.EmployeeName as LeaderName
FROM Contracts c
JOIN Employees m ON m.EmployeeID = c.AreaManager
JOIN Employees l ON l.EmployeeID = c.AreaLeader"
```